# Given hermitian $C$ and diagonal $\Delta$, find $C=H\Delta H^H$ with $H$ orthogonal.

Tags: matrix-equations

Given $C$ a hermitian complex non-singular square matrix, and $\Delta$ real and diagonal with distinct, non-zero diagonal elements, I need to find an orthogonal matrix $H$ such that $$C=H\Delta H^H.$$

Is there a way to do this? One thought was to find the eigendecomposition of $C$: $$C=GDG^H.$$ Since $D$ is also real and diagonal, and $G$ is orthogonal, it has the same structure as the first equation and I thought I might be able to calculate $H$ from $G$ and $D$. However, I haven't been able to make much progress.

Is there a way to determine (a possible, if not unique) $H$ from the assumptions?

(I've found similar questions but none exactly the same; for instance in [Matrix equation with a constraint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110040/matrix-equation-with-a-constraint) the matrix $H$ is not constrained to be orthogonal.)

Comment: Well, you must have conditions on $C$ such as is is Hermitian and the eigenvalues are the same as $\Delta$ otherwise no such $H$ exists.

Comment: I've added the condition that $C$ is hermitian, thanks for pointing out my omission. However, I don't think that $D$ and $\Delta$ are equal. I have a numerical example showing otherwise. I can post it if it would help.

Comment: $D,\Delta$ are not necessarily equal, but the have the same set of values, so there is a permutation matrix $P$ that will rearrange them for you. Replace $G D G^*$ by $G P \Delta P^T G^*$.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks! Most helpful. I also found a scale factor, $x$. So I can write $C=\sqrt{x}GP\Delta P^TG^H\sqrt{x}$. If $J=\sqrt{x}GP$, is it  necessarily the case that each columnt of $H$ is a rotation of the corresponding column of $J$?